# (Tkinter) Trying to updated progress bar value in loop but crashed program?

Tags: python, tkinter, crash, progress-bar

I just want the progress bar to fill when I click the button but anytime I click the button it crashes and I get no error in my console

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter import ttk
from time import sleep

window = Tk()
window.title("Gui Testing")
window.geometry("350x200")

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")
style.configure("black.Horizontal.TProgressbar",background="black")
bar = Progressbar(window,length=200,style="black.Horizontal.TProgressbar")
bar["value"] = 0
bar.grid(column=0,row=0)

def prog():
    i = 0
    while i <= 100:
        sleep(.5)
        i = i + 1
        bar["value"] = i
btn = Button(text="Click",command=prog)
btn.grid(column=0,row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting:

```
ttk.Progressbar(window,length=200,style="black.Horizontal.TProgressbar", mode="determinate")
```